# Evaluate the total mass of a wire

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

A wire has the shape of a curve obtained by the intersection of the portion of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, $y\geq 0$, with the plane $x+z=2$. Knowing that the density in each point of the wire is given by $f(x,y,z)=xy$, evaluate the total mass of the wire.

Well, I found that the curve is given by 
$$\alpha(t)=\left(t,\sqrt{4t-2t^2},2-t\right),$$ 
but the integral was a bit ugly and I couldn't solve. 
So, I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$|\alpha'(t)|^2=\left|\left(1,\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{4t-2t^2},-1\right)\right|^2=1+\frac{2(1-t)^2}{t(2-t)}+1=\frac{2}{{t(2-t)}}.$$
Hence the total mass of the wire can be evaluate by the following line integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{t=0}^2x(t)y(t)|\alpha'(t)|\,dt=\sqrt{2}\int_0^2t\sqrt{t(2-t)}\,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t(2-t)}}\,dt=2\int_0^2 tdt=4.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You can change variables twice, first with $t = 1+u$, then with $v=cos(u)$ :

$$
\begin{align*}
\int{ t \sqrt{4t-2t^2}}\text{d}t &= \int{ t \sqrt{2t(2-t)}}\text{d}t\
\\ &= \int (1+u)\sqrt{2-2u^2}\text{d}u \\
&= \sqrt{2}\int \sqrt{(1-cos^2(v))}(1+cos(v))\text{d}v
\end{align*}$$

Using basic trigonometric formulas ($sin^2v=1-cos^2v$ and $sin(v) cos(v) = \frac{1}{2}sin(2v)$), you can finish the calculation.